# How to run an alias in a shell script?

Tags: bash, scripts, alias

I have an executable file `mpiexec`, whose full path is `~/petsc-3.2-p6/petsc-arch/bin/mpiexec`.  Since I want to execute this command in different directories (without having to retype the entire path), I setup an alias in my home `.bashrc` file:

```
alias petsc="~/petsc-3.2-p6/petsc-arch/bin/mpiexec"
```

which allows me to execute this `mpiexec` file at the command prompt easily by typing:

```
petsc myexecutable
```

I tried to write a shell script file, named `script`, using my new alias `petsc` as a command.  After giving my shell script the appropriate permissions (using `chmod`), I tried to run the script.  However, it gave me the following error:

```
./script: line 1: petsc: command not found
```

I know that I could just write the full path to the `mpiexec` file, but it is cumbersome to write the full path everytime that I want to write a new script.  Is there a way that I can use my alias `petsc` inside the script file?  Is there a way I can edit my `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` to make this happen?

Comment: How about adding the alias to `.bash_aliases` ? Also how about aliasing the absolute path instead of relative path like `alias petsc='/home/user/petsc-3.2-p6/petsc-arch/bin/mpiexec'`

Comment: @nitstorm:  Neither solution seems to work... I still get the same error as before

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/why-doesnt-my-bash-script-recognize-aliases

Comment: I actually just used a system link which worked for me like: `ln -sf /usr/bin/podman .local/bin/docker`

Comment: @NitinVenkatesh You'd have to source your `.bash_aliases` from your `.bashrc`: https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/~/.bash_aliases

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Some options:

1. In your shell script use the full path rather then an alias.
2. In your shell script, set a variable, different syntax

   ```
   petsc='/home/your_user/petsc-3.2-p6/petsc-arch/bin/mpiexec'

   $petsc myexecutable
   ```
3. Use a function in your script. Probably better if `petsc` is complex

   ```
   function petsc () {
       command 1
       command 2
   }

   petsc myexecutable
   ```
4. Source your aliases

   ```
   shopt -s expand_aliases
   source /home/your_user/.bashrc
   ```

You probably do not want to source your `.bashrc`, so IMO one of the first 3 would be better.

Comment: Your suggestion 2) works, but I want to be able to use the same command in multiple shell scripts without having to write the first line petsc="...".  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sounds as if you should put the command in a more standard location, such as `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: In the point 2 you do not set an alias but a variable.

Comment: Not asked for by OP but relevant to the question title: Point 2 won't work with commands containing `|`. Here, use `shopt -s expand_aliases` & local alias, e.g. `alias myalias='echo abc|rev'` - requires line-break before use (see ALIASES in `man bash`).
Point 4: Sourced file may prevent non-interactive execution, i.e. in a script. Look for early `exit` or `return`, e.g. `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` (checks if primary prompt isn't set indicating non-interactive shell) or there may be a check for `i` in `$-` (`$-` contains shell options, `i` means interactive). See `man bash` for those variables.

Comment: I liked option 4. It allowed me to declare and use alias commands within my script

Comment: In case of 4, it is probably better to use `.bash_aliases` file instead of `.bashrc`. Then, only aliases can be sourced.

Comment: I tried to use #4, but it didn't work. Alias in `.bashrc`: `alias sed="sed -E"` Script starts with the two lines from #4, then uses `sed`, but Regexes with `+` still do not work in it. Is this somehow specific to Ubuntu (if yes, why)? I'm using Manjaro.

Comment: Answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1057079/738406 is the correct answer, you have to use `shopt -s expand_aliases`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: *how to use alias in a script*. Workarounds are not useful for everyone else looking for solutions to the question as asked for various reasons and not trying to solve OP's exact problem.

Comment: In my .bashrc file I only set aliases if I'm in an interactive shell (I use `case "$-"` to test if I'm in an interactive shell), so I'm trying to figure out how to refactor my .bashrc so that aliases could be used.  
I was trying to use `petsc` in another script.
I picked option 3 and defined `petsc` as a function.
Another answer says to use `export -f petsc` which seems good as well

Answer (score 113):

Aliases are deprecated in favor of shell functions. From the [bash manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html):

> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.

To create a function and export it to subshells, put the following in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
petsc() {
    ~/petsc-3.2-p6/petsc-arch/bin/mpiexec "$@"
}
export -f petsc
```

Then you can freely call your command from your shell scripts.

Comment: That almost works... the only problem is that I need to be able to pass different flags to the executable "mpiexec"... For instance, I need to be able to execute something like "petsc -n 40 myexecutable" with the alias "petsc"

Comment: @Paul: I added `"$@"` just to handle arguments.

Comment: One of the exception is `return`. Say, you are writing a script that work for both as sourced or standalone, and you want to use `quit` to exit that script. Function like this cannot quit in sourced scritpt:

    quit(){ return $1 ;}

Instead, you need to use alias:

    alias quit=return

Comment: According to `man bash`: ` If the -f option is given, the names refer to functions.`

Comment: At some point the wording must've been softened to "For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases".

Comment: This solution [won't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59360/what-is-the-zsh-equivalent-of-bashs-export-f) with other shells like zshell. Also, exporting functions is a [bad idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug))

Answer (score 43):

```
ALIASES
   ...
   Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt (see the description of shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS
   below).
```

So the real answer to this question, for those looking to use actual aliases in shell scripts instead of alternatives to them, is:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s expand_aliases

alias foo=bar

foo whatever
```

As for *why* I'd want to do this: Due to unusual circumstances, I need to trick a Dockerfile into thinking it's a shell script.

Comment: Yes. This is the right answer. Makes aliases work inside scripts whether invoked from prompt or cron. Thank you.

Comment: This only works for aliases created in the script. Aliases that were present on the system are still ignored; and those are the useful aliases.

Comment: Aliases are not present "in the system". They are present in a given shell process. There is no way for a shell process to transmit its aliases to a child process. The login shell `source`s several files from /etc (the only one I remember is `/etc/profile`), in addition to .profile and .bashrc. If you `source` the same files in your script, you'll have those aliases too.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

In bash 4 you can use special variable: [`$BASH_ALIASES`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html).

For example:

```
$ alias foo="echo test"
$ echo ${BASH_ALIASES[foo]}
echo test
$ echo `${BASH_ALIASES[foo]}` bar
test bar
```

---

Alternatively define as variable then use command substitution or `eval`.

So for example, instead of defining the alias such as:

```
alias foo="echo test"
```

define it as:

```
foo="echo test"
```

instead. Then execute it by either:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c "eval $foo" \;
```

or:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c "echo `$foo`" \;
```

Comment: Altough aliases are deprecated in favor of shell functions, this answer os the only one which should be accepted. Even the old Debian 8 has version 4 of bash, so the `${BASH_ALIASES[alias]}` is a nice option. Otherwise i had to edit lot of lines of my .bash_aliases to apply other things. Thank you.

Comment: Indeed. In my case, it worked like this: eval ${BASH_ALIASES[foo]} . Even managed to get through nested aliasing, e.g. foo->foo123->/smth/real

Comment: It worked in Git Bash on Win 10. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Shell functions and aliases are limited to the shell and do not work in executed shell scripts. Alternatives for your case:

- (if you do not bother to use `mpiexec` instead of `petsc`) Add `$HOME/petsc-3.2-p6/petsc-arch/bin` to your `PATH` variable. This can be done by editing `~/.profile` and appending:

  ```
  PATH="$HOME/petsc-3.2-p6/petsc-arch/bin:$PATH"
  ```

  Re-login to apply these changes
- Create the directory `~/bin` and

  - make a wrapper script named `petsc` containing:

    ```
    #!/bin/sh
    exec ~/petsc-3.2-p6/petsc-arch/bin/mpiexec "$@"
    ```
  - if the program allows for it, you can skip the shellscript and make a symlink using the command:

    ```
    ln -s ~/petsc-3.2-p6/petsc-arch/bin/mpiexec ~/bin/petsc
    ```

Answer (score 16):

You can force bash to execute your script as an interactive shell with the -i flag. This will tell your [.bashrc file](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sample-bashrc.html) to define aliases and other functions.

Example:

```
~ $ grep ll .bashrc
alias ll='ls -lah'
~ $ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/sh

ll
~ $ bash script.sh 
script.sh: line 3: ll: command not found
~ $ bash -i script.sh
..directory contents..
```

More info:

```
$ man bash
```

Comment: `.bashrc` is also read during non-interactive SSH command execution (that's why it has a check for interactivity at the top)

Answer (score 5):

1. In `.bash_aliases`:

   ```
   petsc {
   ~/petsc-3.2-p6/petsc-arch/bin/mpiexec "$@"
   }
   ```

   Or put the function in `.bashrc`. Usually in `.bashrc` only config settings of `bash` are stored.
2. In Terminal: `source .bash_aliases`
3. Call it: `petsc arg(s)`

Advantage: you do not need `export -f petsc`in `.bash_aliases`. Aliases are deprecated but using `.bash_aliases` for functions is ok.

Comment: I like this solution, I will give it a try later

Answer (score 3):

1. Use your aliases in your shell script.
2. Source your script in your current, interactive shell instead of executing it.

So if you have a file called `script.sh` with your commands that include using aliases, simply type:

```bash
source script.sh
```

Comment: @DavidFoerster [This method works fine.](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23775399/) Sourcing a script with the `.` or `source` buiiltin causes the *current* shell to execute all the commands in it. If alias expansion would occur in the shell in which `.` or `source` is run, it occurs. However, it's important to realize that this method is only sometimes useful, because often one needs or wants to execute a script in its own shell, with its own environment. Shell scripts written with the intention of being executed in the usual way should not usually be sourced instead--they often won't work right.

Comment: @EliahKagan: Thanks. Now I understand what the answer is supposed to mean. I'll add an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

(EDIT: removed functions since I misread calling of mpiexec.)

If the only thing you need is less typing, why don't you just put the folder in $PATH? Or make a symlink to mpiexec from some folder in $PATH? Or (my favourite) put the alias in a script that you source in the calling script?

Comment: The reason why I can't put it into my $PATH is because I have another 'mpiexec' file in another directory that is alredy in my $PATH.  If I add the path to this new 'mpiexec', it will probably try to execute both of them... wouldn't it?

Comment: Cannot understand why not simply use `"$@"`.

Comment: Paul, it'll try to execute the one that's first in the PATH, not both.

Comment: enzotib, ah I misread the way mpiexec was called, I thought it needed all args as one. Will edit my answer  :)

Answer (score 1):

Please use `#!/usr/bin/env sh` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, then it works.

sample:
my.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

alias k="kubectl --kubeconfig ~/shop/config"
k version
```

```sh
./my.sh
```

If you have to use `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, then execute the script as the following way:

```sh
sh my.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use case statement like this when in a sub-shell:

```bsh
function execute() {
        case $1 in
                ls) $@ --color=auto ;;
              grep) $@ --color=auto ;;
             fgrep) $@ --color=auto ;;
             egrep) $@ --color=auto ;;
                 *) $@ ;;
        esac
}


( execute $@ )
```