# Running Shell Script on Double Click

Tags: command-line, bash, nautilus, scripts

Okay, I have opened nautilus and edited preferences to ask when I double click an .sh script to run in Terminal. Well, I don't want to use a .desktop file; I want to just simply double click on the .sh file and it run the jar file. This is what I have in my sh script

```
#!/bin/sh

alias proj="cd /home/colby/Desktop/Cauldon\ Server/" 
java -jar cauldron-1.7.10-1.1207.01.198-server.jar -o true
```

This is the error which I get in Terminal

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
Failed to execute child process "/home/colby/Desktop/Cauldon Server/start_server.sh" (No such file or directory)"
```

What is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run an alias in a shell script?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/98782/how-to-run-an-alias-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 1):

From what I see there is an error in the path name either in the desktop file or in the script itself.

Try editing it. Insted of Cauldon Server use Cauldon_Server. Directory name shouldn't include space.

Comment: It works in Terminal but not on double click, you think this could still be an issue?

Comment: Yeah I did what you said and it still did not fix the issue, thank you though.