# alias not working inside bash shell script

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts, alias

When I search for .bashrc files in my system I get:

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
/etc/skel/.bashrc
/root/.bashrc
/usr/share/base-files/dot.bashrc
```

I changed:

```
/etc/bash.bashrc   
/root/.bashrc
```

I added the alias.

```
alias urldecode='python -c "import sys, urllib as ul; \
    print ul.unquote_plus(sys.argv[1])"'

alias urlencode='python -c "import sys, urllib as ul; \
    print ul.quote_plus(sys.argv[1])"'
```

When I run the command:

```
urlencode 'http://example.com space'
```

it works OK from the command line, but when I create an `.sh` file and put the same command there I get:

```
./tf.sh: line 19: urlencode: command not found
```

What is wrong?

Contents of `tf.sh` file:

```
IP=$(curl -d "tool=checurl"-X POST https://site.com/get.py)
url='https://site.com.com/'
path=$(grep -oP '(?<=get.py\?filetype=csv\&data=).*?(?=\")' <<< $IP)
pathfull="get.py?filetype=csv&data=$path"

full=$url$pathfull

#echo $full

urlencode '$full'
```

Comment: please show us the first lines of `tf.sh`

Comment: @Yaron oooo I did

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run an alias in a shell script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98782/how-to-run-an-alias-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: You need to source the `.bashrc` in your script and make it interactive with `set -i`.

Comment: How rovovovo? Show the full command please

Answer (score 10):

Some comments:

1. When writing a bash shell script you are expected to start the script with:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   ```
2. There is a [known issue - Why doesn't my Bash script recognize aliases?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/why-doesnt-my-bash-script-recognize-aliases) - that bash script doesn't recognize aliases.

One option to solve the issue is:

At the beginning of your script (after the `#!/bin/bash`) add:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

Following by `source` of the file with the aliases:

```
source /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Comment: Just did that, didnt work

Answer (score 4):

Bash aliases are usually not expanded in **non interactive** shells (which a script *is*). And really, you shouldn't rely on *aliases* in your scripts!

In the future you'll need the script on a different machine, and you'll forget about
the aliases, and it **won't work**, and you'll waste time debugging the issue!.

Create your scripts to directly use the commands needed. Or create functions for complex or multi-line commands. Or better yet, create a "library" script with common used functions you need and then include *that* on your scripts.

That said, a simple way to call your script with all the aliases exported is to call it through an interactive `bash` session, via the `-i` flag:

```
$> bash -i ./tf.sh
```

#### Edit as per comment

A simple `bash` function wrapper for your `python` script would be:

```
function urldecode {
    PYTHON_ARG="$1" python - <<END
        import sys, urllib as ul
        print ul.unquote_plus(os.environ['PYTHON_ARG'])
    END
}
```

Comment: The alias is a python command
How can I make it to run it directlu onj the scrtipt?
Imn happy with that

Comment: @Bornvs.Me updated my answer

Comment: IS the syntax ok?

./te.sh: line 11: warning: here-document at line 4 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `END')
./te.sh: line 12: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @Bornvs.Me sorry, there should be NO spaces before `END`.

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 1
    import sys, urllib as ul
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent


Python problem now :)

Comment: @Bornvs.Me Sorry, don't know any python :D The text between `<<END` and `END` is passed _verbatim_ to the command. Probably you want to remove all preceding spaces.

Comment: The code doesn't worko

Answer (score 0):

Use 'python2' instead of 'python' in alias. It worked like a charm for me.

```
alias urldecode='python2 -c "import sys, urllib as ul; print ul.unquote_plus(sys.argv[1])"'
```