# How can I execute a command shortcut inside a command in terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash

How can I execute a command shortcut inside a command?
For example, I have: `alias cdp='cd /home/username'` inside `~/.bashrc` and I want to execute: `mv A cdp`,
where `A` is a folder.
But it doesn't work?

Comment: You cannot use an alias as a parameter to a command. In your example, it wouldn't be meaningful anyway... Try to use shell variables instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run an alias in a shell script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98782/how-to-run-an-alias-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: Yes, it does, thank you so much !